# spin-orbit coupling for a rigid body

Tags: classical-mechanics

Consider the motion of a coffee cup in the gravitation field of earth. The force acting on the cup apparently depends on the orientation of the cup. Therefore, the internal rotation (with respect to its center of mass) of the cup is coupled with its center-of-mass motion. Is this a classical counterpart of the spin-orbit coupling in quantum mechanics?

To what extent is the center-of-mass motion modified by the internal motion?

Comment: The gravitational force acting on the cup DOES NOT depend on the orientation of the cup.

Comment: Of course it depends on the orientation. The gravitation field is not a uniform field in the strict sense.

Comment: You are splitting a hair that has already been split multiple times.  Translation - the "non-uniformity" that you are attempting to model cannot be measured by any existing device.  How relevant is a mathematical model that can't be verified by measurement?